# Issue to choose a cell in a section of a TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` with three sections and a variable number of cells for each one and when I tap on a cell, I have a detail view.

I use a segue to send the information to my other view. But I saw that if I the for example the first cell of the second section I will have the first cell of my first section. I tried to fix that by indicating the section and the cell but my program doesn't recognize indexPath.section.

Here is my code of the segue :

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([segue isKindOfClass:[TLAnimatedSegue class]]) {
        ((TLAnimatedSegue *) segue).delegate = self;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        TVDetailsViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.details = [[_scheduleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

I don't understand why I have en error with that because when I `po` my indexPath, I have two element inside. With the breakpoint, this line seems to be the reason of the crash :

```
destViewController.details = [[_scheduleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: as the section index start from 0 you will get section in seqence, 0 1 2 3 ...

Comment: Yes I know that but this line crash the app :`destViewController.details = [[_scheduleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }`

Comment: what did _scheduleList  contains..Please print the array

Comment: _scheduleList is an NSMutableArray which contains different NSString

Comment: `<__NSArrayM 0x7f886aff81c0>(
<TVShow: 0x7f886aff8390>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac1a8a0>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac732a0>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac6fb00>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac91d50>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac74500>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac70e80>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac742c0>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac6fe40>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac710a0>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac725e0>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac9e250>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac721a0>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886aca9710>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac755e0>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac754d0>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac733c0>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac763b0>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac71c50>,
<TVShow: 0x7f886ac712c0>,
)`

Comment: It's a one dimensional array, so you can't apply `objectAtIndex` twice on it. Try show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method for us to see what's your real data in the cell.

Comment: It seems that `_scheduleList` is the data source for your first section, then the question is what's your data for second section.

Comment: I think I know more one part of the issue, scheduleList contains all the data of my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @zcui93 and @Rohit KP, you open my mind and eyes so here is the solution to tackle this little issue and now it works :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue isKindOfClass:[TLAnimatedSegue class]]) {
        ((TLAnimatedSegue *) segue).delegate = self;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        TVDetailsViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        if(indexPath.section == 0) {
            destViewController.details = [_pastScheduleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

        if(indexPath.section == 1) {
        destViewController.details = [_currentScheduleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

        if(indexPath.section == 2) {
            destViewController.details = [_futurScheduleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and get cell content using as describe below and perform segue

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
....
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
String id = cell.textLabel.text;
/*... perform segue operation... */
....
}


/* ...  for( Customcell *cell = (CustomCell*)... ) ...
```